# Polynomial subspace verify

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I verify that $W_1=\{ax^2 - a | a \in \mathbb R\}$ is a subspace, and how do I find a basis of it?

I usually know how to solve this exercise for non-polynomial subspaces, but in this case I'm stuck. I've verified that $0 \in W_1$, so I need to verify other two conditions:

- $\forall v_1,v_2 \in W_1, v_1 + v_2 \in W_1$
- $\forall v \in W_1, k \in \mathbb K, kv \in W_1$

How do I verify these conditions? How do I find a basis of this subspace and, more in general, of a polynomial subspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second condition, you just need to try two different vectors from $W_1$. Let $b_1x^2-b_1, b_2x^2-b_2\in W_1$. Their addition is
$$(b_1+b_2)x^2-(b_1+b_2)$$
Apparently it is also in $W_1$.

The third condition can be tested in a similar way.

The basis is a set of linearly independent vectors that other vectors can be spanned by it. So $\{x^2-1\}$ is a good choice.

Comment: Is there any particular way to find a basis of a polynomial subspace?

Comment: @MathLearner: It really depends on cases. This one is easy to see because all vectors factors into $a(x^2-1)$. You will need just enough vectors to span the others. For example, a subspace with vectors $ax^2+b$ would have a basis $\{x^2, 1\}$ because you have two different arbitrary constants.